# Regular expression replace only if inside { }

Tags: php, regex

I'm wondering how can I replace a character with another in a big string, only if the match is between { }

This:

> ```
> bla bla % bla {ok text %nothing} some {% more} % text {yes %no ok} ok
> ```

To this:

> bla bla % bla {ok text ^^nothing} some {% more} % text {yes ^^no ok}
>   ok

Notice the {% more} wasn't changed because there was a space between the character and the letter.

Your is much appreciated.

Comment: What if the braces are nested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `{}` are **not nested** and no `}` can occur outside of them, you can do things like:

```
preg_replace('/%(?=\w[^{]*})/', '^^', $string);
```

When the string is:

```
bla % bla {ok text %nothing} some {% more} % text {yes %no ok} ok { %foo %bar %baz }
```

you would get:

```
la % bla {ok text ^^nothing} some {% more} % text {yes ^^no ok} ok { ^^foo ^^bar ^^baz }
```

---

If **nested** `{}` are allowed, you could use:

```
%(?=\w([^{}]*+(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*+)*+)})
```

Which works as the first one, with the `[^{]*` being replaced by `([^{}]*+(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*+)*+)`, which is recursively checking for arbitrary nested `{}`.

[Example](http://ideone.com/rOuhY):

```
$string = '%a { %a { %a } %a { { %a } %a } } %a { % %a } %a { %a }';
echo preg_replace('/%(?=\w([^{}]*+(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*+)*+)})/', '^^', $string);
```

Output:

```
%a { ^^a { ^^a } ^^a { { ^^a } ^^a } } %a { % ^^a } %a { ^^a }
```

Comment: This answer is less complex and works better. Great use of the Lookahead.

Comment: am curious about the use of the: `[^{]` Why is it necessary?

Comment: @Tobi, what I'm doing is just checking that there is a `}` following the current `%\w` without any opening `{` in between, thus we're inside `{}`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer I had on SO yet.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = 'bla bla % bla {ok text %nothing} some {% more} % text {yes %no ok} ok';
$str = preg_replace('/(\{[^}]*)%(\w[^}]*)/', '$1^^$2', $str);
// bla bla % bla {ok text ^^nothing} some {% more} % text {yes ^^no ok} ok
```